# Preon detectability and mass

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics

If the mass of the preon is more than the reach of the LHC.. can it still detect any substructure in the quarks, or are these unrelated?

Note: mass of preon can be more than the quark itself if they are canceled by negative binding force contribution.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/394054/2451

Answer (score 0):

I guess it involves two separate procedures.. the first where you do deep inelastic scattering of stationary target nuclei to probe for quark preons.. so even if the preon mass is more than the accelerator energy.. you can still see it.. but then since the say up quark has only 2 MeV mass and the say preon 50 TeV (example) mass is cancelled by the negative binding energy.. can deep inelastic scattering able to disassociate them enough to manifest the preon 50 TeV mass?  The second procedure just involves typical moving proton-to-proton collision where extra bumps and resonance can be seen in the detector if the accelerator energy is more than the quark preons, here it sure depends on the energy of the accelerator.