# LHC Constraints on Quark Preon 2018

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, beyond-the-standard-model

What is the most updated March 2018 Constraints on quarks preon (subquarks) detection? What reference or source to look for the latest summary about exclusions of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [CERN document server](http://cds.cern.ch/).

For example, I found for CMS  "preon limits" in the [following link:](http://cds.cern.ch/search?ln=en&p=cms%20preon%20limits&action_search=Search&op1=a&m1=a&p1=&f1=&c=CERN%20Document%20Server&sf=&so=d&rm=&rg=10&sc=1&of=hb) from 2012 data:

> Another reinterpretation can be done in terms of four-fermion contact interaction (Helicity-Non-Conserving model),  providing a limit on the preon binding energy scale Λ .

there is also a thesis.

for quarks nothing came up.

Atlas came out with nothing . Not a very popular subject.

Comment: In quark deep inelastic scattering.. they used target nuclei like in the Rutherford scattering of gold nuclei in detecting nucleons.. how about at LHC.. what stationary target nuclei do they use to probe for possible preons?